# Visual studio doesn't open any of the new files

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Recently I am having a problem when opening solution with visual Studio. Let's say I create files and push them, then clone the repo somewhere new and open it from there; it will not open the new files. Every single time I have to click Add -> Add existing files to each one of the new files.
It is very frustrating, it also does this when I open project on the branch of my coworkers and it is such a mess because I do not know which files haven't been loaded yet and have to find them out through the errors.

Are there any fixes to this?

Comment: When you push the changes, are you saving the solution and pushing the changes to the *.csproj?

Comment: I have not, I usually simply push the .cs files I changed. With your answer I am guessing the .csproj is what tells the files to be open?

Comment: The csproj file is what keeps track of the packages and files (among other stuff) of the project. You need to always push that file or you will run into serious problems.

Comment: What about the .csproj.user? Should this one be pushed too or is it a "personnal" file?

Comment: That is only for your own settings (like files opened in VS and some settings like the project's path in your hard drive), you can keep that locally. You will have conflicts if you push that

Answer (score 0):

Fixing what you started with is potentially a very difficult exercise, because it's unclear what project structure you've got now and which files have been included/excluded from your Visual Studio files list.

Thus, if it's an option for your--and to make life easy on yourself--start afresh with a new Visual Studio project. You can use Visual Studio's File | New | Project menu. Choose the type of project you're working with (you didn't say in your post), then check the Create new Git repository checkbox before clicking OK. At that point, Git creates an important .gitignore file in your repo's root folder--and that file will ensure that the correct files are getting excluded from your future check-ins...

Once you've got a virginal project properly configured for Git in Visual Studio, add your files to it and check them in when done.

Now when you push your local repo, the remote will then have all the files anyone would need to pull/clone and work on another workstation.